# Difficulty using SELECT SUM in a query USING SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
WITH rows AS
    (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS rn
    FROM    [AVL_Ignition]
    )
SELECT  mc.[DeviceIMEI], (mp.TimeStamp - mc.TimeStamp) as millisecond, mc.Value, mc.Tag
FROM    rows mc
JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

this query is working correctly and is returning me the following values

```
DeviceIMEI| milissecond|value
   123    |     184    |1
   123    |     184    |0
   123    |     184    |1
   123    |     184    |0
   123    |     184    |1
   123    |     184    |0
```

I am wanting to add the values ​​in the millisecond field where value = 1

I'm trying to use **SELECT SUM** as follows but I'm not getting a result

```
SELECT mc.[DeviceIMEI], SUM (WITH rows AS
    (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) AS rn
    FROM    [AVL_Ignition]
    )
SELECT (mp.TimeStamp - mc.TimeStamp) as millisecond
FROM    rows mc
JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1) where mc.Value = 1;
```

I know that SELECT SUM is not complicated to use but I'm having trouble doing this with this query

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it without using `SUM` in this case. If you are on SQL Server 2012+ you can use the `IIF` function like this (just leave your `WITH` section where it is):

```
SELECT
  mc.DeviceIMEI
, (mp.TimeStamp - mc.TimeStamp) + IIF(mc.Value = 1, 1, 0) AS millisecond
, mc.Value
, mc.Tag
```

Otherwise you have to use a `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  mc.DeviceIMEI
, (mp.TimeStamp - mc.TimeStamp) + CASE
                                    WHEN mc.Value = 1 THEN mc.Value
                                    ELSE 0
                                  END AS millisecond
, mc.Value
, mc.Tag
```